# Webdriver.io test runner - exclude suite from specific capability

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io, saucelabs

My webdriver.io test runner is organized into suites, and I want to exclude a suite from a specific capability.

For example, I have a suite called `suite1`:

```
//
suites: {
  suite1: [
    './test/spec/*.js',
  ],
},
//
```

And I want to exclude this suite from the Safari capability:

```
//
{
    'tunnelIdentifier' : sltunnel,
    'browserName': 'safari',
    'version': '10',
    'platform': 'OS X 10.12',
    'screenResolution': '1600x1200',
    'exclude':  [
        suite1,
     ],
},
//
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are multiple ways to do this, but at the end of the day it's all up to you.

You can drag your entire suite logic outside of your `wdio.conf.js` file into a separate config file (I'm sure you might already have one for your environments: **test**, **prod**, w/e) and then import it (via `require` into your `wdio.conf.js` file):

So let's say you have `suites.conf.js` file:

```
module.exports.suites = {
    // 1 => run the suite
    // 0 => don't run it
    "chrome": {
        "0": [
            "<yourSuiteName-001>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-003>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-005>.js"
        ],
        "1": [
            "<yourSuiteName-002>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-004>.js"
        ]
    },
    "safari" : {
        "0": [
            "<yourSuiteName-002>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-004>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-005>.js"
        ],
        "1": [
            "<yourSuiteName-001>.js"
            "<yourSuiteName-003>.js"
        ]
    }
// <etc>
}
```

Then you import it into your `wdio.conf.js` file (`var suites = require(./<pathToSuitesConfig>/suites.conf.js);`), cycle with a `forEach` through all your suites and based on your `browserName`, create a buffer in which you store the **runable** suites as they match your condition, then add them into the config file. This logic will go in your `wdio.conf.js` header section and you can update the exportable `config` via the results.

I just thought of this in like 5 minutes, so I'm sure there's multiple cleaner ways to achieve this.

---

Alternatively, you can look at other test-runners that are easy to plug into WebdriverIO and which have *tagging*:

- Cucumber has a great **[tagging](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)** mechanism (due to Gherkin syntax);
- Mocha has something similar called, you guessed it **[tagging](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Tagging)**.